# What to do with the biases in an autoencoder/decoder if you want to tie the weights

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder

I understand how to tie the weights in an autoencoder/decoder, i.e. use the transpose of the encoder weights in the decoder.  However, it is unclear what to do with the biases.

If for example,

**Encoder:**
4 Features -> 3 Hidden -> 2 Hidden

**Decoder:**
2 Hidden -> 3 Hidden -> 4 Features'

As the biases for a layer are the number of nodes in the next layer they are not symmetric.

In the above example the biases would be 3,2,3,4

However as the Encoder and Decoder are symmetric but in reverse there are 2 biases that are the same size i.e. 3.

**Question 1:**
Do I tie these similar sized biases?

**Question 2:**
The ones that I don't tie, if the answer to question 1 is no, or can't tie, the asymmetric ones, are they simply independent variables?

Comment: I was wondering exactly the same. I read that it's not necessary but you could add it as well, but I couldn't find any proper explanation about why.

Comment: I have just encountered this problem when building my first autoencoder - does anyone have a solution?